# How can I use my handle number?

Tags: autoit

I have 2 windows that have the same title. So, I have to detect them by handle. They use very long time to begin from the beginning of my code, too. So I have to begin them before, then debug the middle of code by detect them by their handle. The codes are difference between them, so I must specify the handle by my hand. However, thank you very much.

I got my own  window's handle number by Au3Info application.

But It didn't work when I use like this:

```
;run Au3Info.exe to get calc.exe window's handle number
;then activate minimizing calc.exe by copied window's handle number  from  Au3Info.exe

Run("C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\Au3Info.exe")
WinWaitActive("(Frozen) AutoIt v3 Window Info")
WinSetOnTop("(Frozen) AutoIt v3 Window Info", "", 0)
WinMove("(Frozen) AutoIt v3 Window Info","",0,0)
Run("calc.exe")
WinWaitActive("Calculator")
Winmove("Calculator","",500,500)
WinActivate("(Frozen) AutoIt v3 Window Info")
WinWaitActive("(Frozen) AutoIt v3 Window Info")
MouseClickDrag("left",261, 156,505,505)
MouseClick("left",136, 374,10) ;copy calculator window's handle number form Au3Info
WinSetState ( "Calculator", "",   @SW_MINIMIZE  )
WinActivate(ClipGet ( ))

;$hWnd=0x004D01DE ; window's handle number copy from Au3Info
;ConsoleWriteError(@crlf & WinActivate($hWnd) & @crlf)
```

Above, I want to active current session 0x004D01DE-handle windows, but it didn't work, returned me "0", not found specific window. Although the window's handle number still be the same, when I recheck.

I debugging some part of my script, so I have to copy the specific handle window's number by myself to save a long period of time for debugging from the full code.

Did I use that window's handle number in right way?

Comment: What do you mean by "my own handle number"? Handle to what?

Comment: window's handle number

Comment: Yes, but *which* window? Every window has a handle, but not only top-level windows but even sub-windows within top-level windows, and also non-visualized windows. So you must be much more specific and clear with your question and your code. Consider creating and posting a valid [mcve] with your question.

Comment: Do you mean the handle for your own AutoIt GUI window? Also, you do know that the handle number changes each time the application is run, and so hard-coding the number is not a useful thing to do.

Comment: Above, I want to active current session 0x004D01DE-handle windows, but it didn't work. Although the window's handle number still be the same, when I recheck.

Comment: Again, please consider creating a **small** complete runnable AutoIt program, and posting it, one we can run and test ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [`HWnd()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HWnd.htm). Just change `WinActivate(ClipGet())` to `WinActivate(HWnd(ClipGet()))`.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason to use `Au3Info.exe`. `WinWaitActive` already returns the handle. Just use it:

```
Run("calc.exe")
$hCalc=WinWaitActive("Calculator")
MsgBox(0,"Handle","Calculatior's handle is: " & $hCalc)
WinMove($hCalc,"",500,500)
WinSetState($hCalc,"",@SW_MINIMIZE)
```

Another possibility is `WinGetHandle`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot to tell the reason. I have 2 windows that have the same title. So, I have to detect them by handle. They use very long time to begin from the beginning of my code, too. So I have to begin them before, then debug the middle of code by detect them by their handle. The codes are difference between them, so I must specify the handle by my hand. However, thank you very much.

Comment: ah, ok. And `WinList` doesn't help because you don't know which is which, i guess.

Comment: Yes, I have tried WinList, but I still have to test  each result of it to know which window that it refer to. So, Au3Info.exe is easier in this case.